# Which characters are supported for single line comments in Javadoc options files?

Tags: java, javadoc

Javadoc supports options files to be used like the following:

```
javadoc @optsFile1 @optsFile2 @optsFile3
```

The format of that files doesn't seem to be [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) too much:

> The arguments within a file can be space-separated or newline-separated. If a file name contains embedded spaces, then put the whole file name in double quotation marks.

I've successfully tried to use lines beginning with the character `#` and those seem to be ignored during processing argument files. But I couldn't find any official documentation if comments in those files are supported at all and if so which, e.g. single-line only vs. multi-line etc. Single-line is most likely already, but maybe those support additional characters like `//`?

**So, which characters are supported for single line comments in Javadoc options files?**

- `#` most likely

Comment: Since it doesn’t say you can embed a comment in an argument file, I’m surprised `#` works at all.  I would not rely on it.  If I felt a comment were necessary, I would place it in a shell script before the `javadoc` command itself.